# htaccess to rewrite image url from other site

Tags: image, .htaccess, url-rewriting, cloaking

i want to rewrite image url from other site, example :

image from other site:

```
http://othersite.com/images/dir/image1.jpg
```

i want to cloak that link to :

```
http://mysite.com/images/dir/image1.jpg
```

now i use this htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^images/dir/(.*)$ http://othersite.com/images/dir/$1 [L,R=301]
```

it's working, **but** when the link is opened it will turn into the original link, i want visitors will still see the link does not change to the original link

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the R=301 so its still forwarding the request but not rewriting the url. And if the other site is not your own, you should really ask permission to use their images. Besides copyright issues, Hotlinking is technically stealing bandwidth, and its not difficult to detect and shut down if the webmaster knows what hes doing....